# About Suggester component

Tags: solr

I am a newbie in solr. Recently I have installed solr 3.4 for my undergrad thesis purpose. I have tried to configure  suggester component by the reference of  http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/15/solr-and-autocomplete-part-2/
it did not give me the actual result  after following  all instruction and code. 
after query http://localhost:8983/solr/suggest?q=har   I got

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">32</int>
   </lst>
   <lst name="spellcheck">
      <lst name="suggestions"/>
   </lst>
</response>
```

Where the actual one  was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>    
   <lst name="responseHeader">    
      <int name="status">0</int>    
      <int name="QTime">0</int>    
   </lst> 
   <lst name="spellcheck">
   <lst name="suggestions">    
   <lst name="dys">    
      <int name="numFound">4</int>   
      <int name="startOffset">0</int>    
      <int name="endOffset">3</int>   
      <arr name="suggestion">    
        <str>hard drive</str>    
        <str>hard drive samsung</str>    
        <str>hard drive seagate</str>    
        <str>hard drive toshiba</str>    
      </arr>    
   </lst>    
  </lst>    
 </lst>    
</response>
```

I am assuming that I am not getting the suggestion .
I dont know whether am I wrong or not . It will be very helpful for me if someone clear my confusion and how could I approach further if   I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Did you build the dictionary? And does the name_autocomplete field actually hold the example data?